# Generating Multiple Divi Pages from Database

Tags: plugin-development, pages, page-template

I have a template in Divi that I want to use as the basis for generating hundreds of pages. I would like to replace some terms in the title of the page, as well as the body of the page, based on data stored in a table or CSV. Is there a way to do this programmatically? I would like to generate a sufficiently high number of pages that doing this broadly would be best.

If not, how would this be done without using a Divi page?

Thank you!